# Hibernate Caching does not improve performance

Tags: hibernate, caching, apache-camel, spring-orm

My Application-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
..
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    ..
default-autowire="byName">

<import resource="jms-context.xml" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:res.properties" />

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="..." />


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" />
</bean>


<bean id="pooledDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.database.driverClass}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.database.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.database.password}" />
     ...
</bean>

<bean id="GLOBAL" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:URL="${jdbc.database.url}" p:user="${jdbc.database.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.database.password}">
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="MinLimit" value="${jdbc.database.minLimit}" />
            <entry key="MaxLimit" value="${jdbc.database.maxLimit}" />
            <entry key="InitialLimit" value="${jdbc.database.initialLimit}" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="global-tm" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="global-em" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="GLOBAL" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="global-em" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.hibernate.dialectClass}" />
</bean>

<bean id="global-em"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:packagesToScan="..." p:dataSource-ref="pooledDataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" />
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


 </beans>
```

I have annotated my entities as follows :

```
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;

@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
```

The DSL in the Camel Route Builder is as follows:

```
from(fromURI)
     ...
    .policy(required)
    .bean(bean1, "proc") 
        ...
        .recipientList().method(recipientList, "endPoint")
    ...
    .end();
```

But I could not discern any tangible improvement. Am I missing something?

My constraints are:

1. I can not use Hibernate like (org.hibernate.annotations.Cache) directly in my code as my code needs to JPA compliant.
2. My entities are annotated. So, beans can not be configured Cacheable via hbm.xml

Comment: You say _I can not use Hibernate like (`org.hibernate.annotations.Cache`)_ but you _have_. Could you explain what your example it trying to show exactly?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, sorry for the confusion. Even I've tried with Hibernate directly, but of no avail. I need to use Spring-JPA underlying configuration will be on Hibernate

Answer (score -1):

use this hibernate factory

net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory

instead of

org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

I have been using ehcache for some time in my project and its surely reducing no. of queries fired.

Please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I'm using Hibernate 4.1.12.Final  ;   http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate#Configure-Ehcache-as-the-Second-Level-Cache-Provider  recommends org.hibernate.cache.ehcache instead of net.sf.ehcache.hibernate package.  Of course I shall try with org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory ASAP. Please let me  know your idea.

Comment: The difference between these two is the the `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` returns the _same_ cache instance for each `SessionFactory` created whereas the `EhCacheRegionFactory` returns a _different_ cache instance for each `SessionFactory`. Whether you use one or other other affects _where_ things are cached and **not** the speed.